# Creating specific date object from milliseconds in different time

Tags: java, date, datetime

I'm working with an API that has a different time than the program's machine. I can retrieve the time of the server, which will returns milliseconds.

e.g

```
long serverTime = api.getTime()
```

Since I know the server time, can I somehow create a date object from this millisecond that would represent certain dates, but with server time?

For example, API is only available from 8:00 to 16:00 UTC (machine time is +1 hour). My use case requires me to send data using this API as soon as possible (the sooner I send data, the sooner they get processed, and the sooner other tasks can start running and so on, unfortunately, every millisecond spared is good). So far I am doing something like this

```
// create date time when i want to do something with API in my time
 LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 3, 26, 9, 0, 0);
 long targetMillis = time.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();

 long serverTime = api.getTime()
 // calculate diff
 long serverTimeDiff = client.getServerTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();

// sleep thread till the time is right. Sleep 1 minute less to start busy waiting to get some extra 
// spared millis
 Thread.sleep((targetMillis - serverTime) - minutesToMilliseconds(1) );
 while( System.currentTimeMillis() + serverTimeDiff < ( targetMillis - 50 ) ){
        //busy waiting
 }
  
 api.sendData(..);
```

However, the time diff may not be that accurate (change in few millis), is there some way how to create something like:

```
long serverTime = api.getTime()
Instant date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(serverTime).setHour(..).setMinute(..).setSecond(..);
```

So I can calculate the diff more accurately with something like

```
Thread.sleep((targetMillis - date.toMillis().toEpochMilli) - minutesToMilliseconds(1))
```

and thus possibly save some milliseconds?

Comment: Well, most of the times, the integer number you get is already in UTC, so a conversion involving timezones may be unnecessary.

Comment: What does "8:00 to 16:00 UTC ( machine time is +1 hour )" mean? What is "machine time"?

Comment: Are you asking how to start a task at 08:00 UTC?

Comment: What *exactly* is "long serverTime = api.getTime()"? Is this the server reporting the current moment as a count of milliseconds since an [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of first moment of 1970 UTC (1970-01-01T00:00Z)? Perhaps [some other epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing)? If you do not know, you need to find out.

Comment: *a different time than the program's machine*, is that because of a different time zone (like Central European Time, for example), or is it because the machine’s clock is set incorrectly? The solution is quite different in those two cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is quite unclear. But I am guessing that you want to start a task at 08:00 UTC.

If so, use a scheduled executor service to run your [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) or `Callable` task on a background thread at the appropriate time.

Determine your next target moment, the next 8 AM in UTC. To do this, you will need the current date and current time as seen in UTC. If right now is not before 8 AM, you must add a day to the date. Then combine that date with the specified time of 8 AM to get a moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

Calculate the amount of elapsed time until that target moment. Use that amount of time as the *delay* argument to the [`schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method of your [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

```java
package work.basil;

import java.time.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * By Basil Bourque. http://www.Basil.work/ 
 * https://stackoverflow.com/q/66809336/642706
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - demo method starting. " + Instant.now() );

        // Using lambda syntax to define a `Runnable` object as the task to be done at specified moment.
        // You could just as well write a conventional class that implements `Runnable` (or `Callable`). 
        Runnable task = ( ) -> {
            System.out.println( "Sending data at: " + Instant.now() );
        };

        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        // Calculate time to wait until the next 8 AM.
        LocalTime targetTime = LocalTime.of( 8 , 0 );
        OffsetDateTime nowUtc = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC );
        LocalDate targetDate = nowUtc.toLocalDate();
        if ( ! nowUtc.toLocalTime().isBefore( targetTime ) )
        {
            targetDate = targetDate.plusDays( 1 );
        }
        OffsetDateTime targetUtc = OffsetDateTime.of( targetDate , targetTime , ZoneOffset.UTC );
        Duration duration = Duration.between( nowUtc , targetUtc );
        System.out.println( "INFO - Your task is waiting  = " + duration + " to run at: " + targetUtc + " which is: " + targetUtc.atZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) + "." );
        long delay = duration.toNanos();

        ses.schedule( task , delay , TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS );

        // … Eventually shutdown your executor service so its backing pool of threads do not continue indefinitely like a zombie ‍.
        ses.shutdown();
        ses.awaitTermination();
        System.out.println( "INFO - demo method ending. " + Instant.now() );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
INFO - demo method starting. 2021-03-26T03:15:03.203895Z
INFO - Your task is waiting  = PT4H44M56.786492S to run at: 2021-03-26T08:00Z which is: 2021-03-26T01:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles].
```